# Can Game Center Track total time played?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

Curious to know if Game Center tracks total time played per app? If it does, how could I easily query this data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use game center to do this. There are a couple of options though.

You can track it locally, and then upload the data to a game center leaderboard. I don't know if you want to do that though because then everyone can see how much a certain player has played

You can use some sort of analytics service, like Google Analytics and ping it periodically while a player is on the app so you can see how much people are playing

Or you can set up a server and database, where the player sends their play time when they are on the app